# First and second name initials, preserving full surname

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's my first touch with javascript and I really need help. I have an html with divs containing from one to three "author" text values each. I need to make automate shorting the names (only first names) if there is more than one "author" in div.
Eg.

```
<div class="book">
        <a> <h2>Book 1</h2>
        <h3 class="author">Minty Estelle</h3>
        <h3 class="author">Katey Josepha Shevon</h3></a></div>

<div class="book">
        <a> <h2>Book 2</h2>
        <h3 class="author">Leila Seward</h3></a></div>
```

So that output would be:

```
Book 1 
M. Estelle  
K.J. Shevon

Book 2 
Leila Seward
```

So if there is only one "author" - his name stays unchanged. But if it's more than one - firstname and secondname (but not surname - last value) is shortened to first leter and followed by dot.

I searched a lor and played with compilations... but nothing worked. Is anyone can help to find a solution?
My js so far is:

```
    var authorName = $(".book h3");
  authorName.each(function(){
  if(authorName.length > 1 && authorName.hasClass("author")){
    var names = authorName.split(" ");
    var shortened = names.not(:lastChild).map(s => s.slice(0, 1).append(". "));
    document.authorName.innerHTML = shortened;
  }
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. We'll gladly help you.

Comment: Just added the js code.. but as I told, it's my first try and I'm just a beginner, so there is probably not much sense in it.

Comment: I added a working example below and commented the logic behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to loop over your books, then loop over every author of said book :

```js
//For each book
$('.book').each(function() {
  //If the book has more than one author
  if ($('h3.author', this).length > 1) {
    //For each author
    $('h3.author', this).each(function() {
      //Store the author name before emptying it
      var words = $(this).text().split(' ');
      $(this).text('');

      //For each word inside the author name
      for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        //If it's not the last name
        if (i < words.length - 1) {
          //Only keep the first letter
          $(this).text($(this).text() + words[i].substring(0, 1) + '. ');
        //Else keep the whole word
        } else $(this).text($(this).text() + words[i]);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="book">
  <a>
    <h2>Book 1</h2>
    <h3 class="author">Minty Estelle</h3>
    <h3 class="author">Katey Josepha Shevon</h3>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="book">
  <a>
    <h2>Book 2</h2>
    <h3 class="author">Leila Seward</h3>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple version, Adjust it for your own needs, and maybe refactor it to be more in functional way :)

```js
/*
So that output would be:

Book 1 
M. Estelle  
K.J. Shevon

Book 2 
Leila Seward*/
$(".book").each(function() {

  var authors = $('h3.author', this);

  if (authors.length > 1) {
    authors.each(function() {

    var result = $(this).text().split(' ').map(function(name, index, arr) {
      return index < arr.length - 1 ? name[0]+'.' : name;
    }).join(' ');

    $(this).text(result);
   });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="book">
        <a> <h2>Book 1</h2>
        <h3 class="author">Minty Estelle</h3>
        <h3 class="author">Katey Josepha Shevon</h3></a></div>

<div class="book">
        <a> <h2>Book 2</h2>
        <h3 class="author">Leila Seward</h3></a></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Eugene! Works as a charm! Both of replies were solving my problem.